# how to send an email alert if backup fails via SQL Job

Tags: sql, t-sql, email, backup, alert

I'm going to run via a `SQL Job` a backup which will back up 4 databases.  What I want to do is to be able to send an email via my `Database Mail profile` if any of the backup's fail.

Now I know there is a very obvious way of doing this on the job itself but my boss doesn't want it done like that.

What we want is within the `T-SQL` code for the job is to be able to detect the backup failing or the job itself failing and then send the email.

I hope I've explained the issue.

Thanks to everyone in advance who may have some ideas for me.

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a spin:

```
BEGIN TRY
BACKUP LOG @v_DatabaseName TO DISK = @v_BackupFileLocation WITH NAME = @v_BackupFileName, SKIP, STATS = 10
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
Set @v_ErrorMailSubject = 'Transaction log backup failure in database '+@v_DatabaseName
Set @v_ErrorMailText = 'An error occured in transaction log backup for database '+@v_DatabaseName+'.'+Char(13)+Char(13)
Set @v_ErrorMailText = @v_ErrorMailText + 'Error '+Cast(Error_Number() as nvarchar)+' - ['+Error_Message()+']'
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    @recipients=@v_ErrorMailRecipient, 
                @subject = @v_ErrorMailSubject,
                @body = @v_ErrorMailText
END CATCH
```

[You'll need to configure the database email configurations first, though](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)

Comment: Thanks very much indeed - does exactly what I asked for.